# Fowarding ARP requests using DPTCL on a mininet machine

Tags: mininet, openflow, sdn

I have a very simple 3 hosts, 1 switch topology which has been illustrated in the image attached.

[image: Topography]

I am trying to write a dpctl command such that an ARP request from host 1 is sent to host 3.

This is the command I am trying to use:

```
 dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6634 idle_timeout=0,in_port=1,dl_type=0x0806,actions=output:3
```

However, when I try to ping host3 from host1, I do not see any packets reaching host3.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked that the flow is getting installed on the switch correctly?

Comment: The flow is getting installed correctly. Anyway, I figured out the problem and answered the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that I was passing the argument `--arp` when setting up the topology of the network which automatically fills up the ARP tables of each of the hosts. As a result, host1 doesn't send an ARP request as it already knows the MAC address of the destination host. Removing this argument fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to install 2 flows. One for sending the ARP request and one for receiving it. In particular, the controller knows how to send the ARP request from host 1 to host 3, but in particular it doesn't know how to forward the ARP respond from host 3 to host 1. 
You would have two flows installed. Something like these:

```
dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6634 idle_timeout=0,in_port=1,dl_type=0x0806,actions=output:3
dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6634 idle_timeout=0,in_port=3,dl_type=0x0806,actions=output:1
```

Note that I am using your own piece of code and I assumed that the syntax and format is right. Let me know if it helped.

And of course as @Nik suggested, check to see if the flow is installed.

Comment: Hi. The problem wasn't that host1 wasn't getting the ARP response from host3 but that host3 wasn't getting the ARP request from host1 at all. Anyway, I figured out the problem and answered the question. Thanks!